unable to update relationshipAttributeDefs in apache atlas
I have added an entity type called oracle_table in atlas. Now I am trying to add following to that entity. but I am getting following error .
Failed to update type definition. Status code: 500
Response content: bThere was an error processing your request. It has been logged.
'''

    new_relationship_attribute = [
    {
      "name": "columns",
      "typeName": "array<oracle_column>",
      "isOptional": True,
      "cardinality": "SET",
      "valuesMinCount": -1,
      "valuesMaxCount": -1,
      "isUnique": False,
      "isIndexable": False,
      "includeInNotification": False,
      "searchWeight": -1,
      "constraints": [
        {
          "type": "ownedRef"
        }
      ],
      "relationshipTypeName": "oracle_table_columns",
      "isLegacyAttribute": True
    }
]

updated_relationships = [attr for attr in oracle_table_type_def['relationshipAttributeDefs'] if attr['name'] != 'columns']
updated_relationships.append(new_relationship_attribute)
oracle_table_type_def['relationshipAttributeDefs'] = updated_relationships
print(oracle_table_type_def)
update_type_def_url = f"https://URL:31443/api/atlas/v2/types/typedef"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
update_response = requests.put(update_type_def_url, headers=headers, 
                               data=json.dumps(oracle_table_type_def), auth=auth)
if update_response.status_code == 200:
    print("Successfully updated the oracle_table type definition.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to update type definition. Status code: {update_response.status_code}")
    print("Response content:", update_response.content)


'''

